# KVM with IDE drivers

Tags: drivers, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I've spent about a week installing and destroying a KVM install, and in the last two days have finally managed to get it working and understand the process.

What I have is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64 host running and working. I've setup a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS guest which I have installed webvirtmgr on and that is working well.

I can now create machines and manage them through webvirtmgr but have hit one small issue which I am not sure how to solve. A linux product that I am trying to setup on a VM does not have support for the virtio divers so when it runs it can not pick up the virtual disk assigned to the guest.

I have set this product up before on a hosted provider and had the same issue the, but they had the option to choose a ide driver for the disk. I understand the IDE drivers are not as fast as the virtio drivers, but at the moment I would just like to get the product working.

I can't see anywhere inside webvirtmgr to set the disk as an IDE disk but not sure if that is a limitation of the way I have set it up or if I need to add something to the host to make this available to webvirtmgr.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

So I so looks like I managed to solve the issue. I edited the xml file of the vm specifically the part relating to the virtual disk drive I changed it from

```
<disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
      <source file='/srv/storage/images/kerio_control.img'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
```

to

```
<disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/srv/storage/images/kerio_control.img'/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
```

I also then had an issue with the network card and doing some hunting I changed the following as well

```
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:11:c4:3b'/>
  <source bridge='br0'/>
  <target dev='vnet2'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <alias name='net0'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

to

```
<interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:11:c4:3b'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <target dev='vnet2'/>
      <model type='e1000'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
```

Which was just changing the model type from virtio to e1000